# Get URL segment in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

For accessing previous URL in laravel. I am using this code in my controller.

```
$current_url = Request::url();
$back_url = redirect()->back()->getTargetUrl();
if ($current_url != $back_url) {
  Session::put('previous_url', redirect()->back()->getTargetUrl());
}
```

This method helps maintainging previous url even when server side validation fails.
In my blade I access previous url like this `{{ Session::get('previous_url') }}`.

I need to find the second segment of my previous url.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by second segment? Can you give an example?

Comment: www.example.com/segment1/segment2/12/114/122 - I need this segment 2 sir iin laravel way,if exists.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way:

```
request()->segment(2);
```

`request()` is a helper function that returns *Illuminate\Http\Request*, but you can also use the facade *Request* or inject the class as a dependency in your method.

**EDIT**

with the redirect back: `redirect()->back()->getRequest()->segment(2);`

Comment: `redirect()->back()->getTargetUrl()` returns back url with params.need to extract the second segment.

Comment: @ShakunChaudhary my mistake, I didn't understand that you want the segment from the previous URL. Please check my edit.

Comment: i need segment from target url.If i use this  `redirect()->back()->getRequest()->segment(2)`.It gives segment of current url not from previous url.

Comment: @ShakunChaudhary aah yes, but `redirect()->back()` returns *RedirectResponse* object which cant access the segments. So in this case use **getTargetUrl()** and parse it like @Chris suggests.

Comment: I also feel the same.but in chris method, what is `return Arr::`.May be he just copy pasted.so now i have to do this in php way.Thanks @TheFallen

Comment: @ShakunChaudhary this is *Illuminate\Support\Arr* and **get()** is to get an item from the array.

Answer (score 2):

Under the hood, Laravel is doing these two things to get the segments of a url (from within the Request class):

```
public function segment($index, $default = null)
{
    return Arr::get($this->segments(), $index - 1, $default);
}

public function segments()
{
    $segments = explode('/', $this->path());

    return array_values(array_filter($segments, function ($v) {
        return $v != '';
    }));
}
```

You could do something similar in a helper function:

```
public function segment($url, $index, $default)
{
    return Arr::get($this->segments($url), $index - 1, $default);
}


public function segments($url)
{
    $segments = explode('/', $url);

    return array_values(array_filter($segments, function ($v) {
        return $v != '';
    }));
}
```